# Is there a way to access the function's pre-bind values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bind

Like this:

```
const a = (arg0, arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log(arg0);
};
const b = a.bind(null, 1, 2, 3)
```

Now suppose I only have **b**, is it possible to get the pre-bind value list of a? I mean the value 1, 2, 3

If it is possible, how?

Comment: If you had all these params in some variable, than yes, else you can't. Same like in `var b = 5 + 2` and *get* 2...

Comment: @Justinas not exactly, I have b, so if I do b.call(), then the arguments is certain, so i am wondering: since it is certain, can i know it in some way?

Comment: So you want to get all parameters passed to function inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your own bind function you can attach new properties to it, A function can have properties added to it like any other object.

```js
function bind(fn, thisArg, ...boundArgs) {
  const func = function(...args) {
    return fn.call(thisArg, ...boundArgs, ...args)
  }
  // you can hide the properties from public view using 
  // defineProperties, unfortunately they are still public
  Object.defineProperties(func, {
    __boundArgs: { value: boundArgs },
    __thisArg: { value: thisArg },
    __boundFunction: { value: fn }
  })
  return func
}

const a = (a, b, c) => console.log(a, b, c)

const b = bind(a, null, 1, 2, 3)

b()

console.log(b.__boundArgs)
console.log(b.__thisArgs)
console.log(b.__boundFunction)
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

The first argument to `Function.prototype.bind` is the `this` arg.

To answer the question, if you are using chrome you can access the info in the property `[[BoundArgs]]` on the bound function. run the code and Check your console

```js
const a = (arg0, arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log(arg0, arg1, arg2);
};
const b = a.bind(null, 1, 2, 3)
b()
console.dir(b)
```

Comment: I can see the BoundArgs is there, but how can i get it?

Comment: I am in Node.js env, I can see the BoundArgs is there with console.dir() in console, but how can i get it?
t.bound()
VM501:1 Uncaught TypeError: t.bound is not a function(…)

Comment: Don't think you can.. you could always write your own bind function.. it's only a few lines